# Pandas apply() -- Function Returns Dictionary Unknown Length and Keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a function that returns a dictionary. I'd like to execute this function on a DataFrame, and I do like

```
import pandas as pd
def func(x):
    d = {'B': x+1, 'C': x+2}
    return d
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(5)})
df[['B','C']] = df.apply(lambda x: func(x['A']), axis=1, result_type='expand')
df
    A   B   C
0   0   1   2
1   1   2   3
2   2   3   4
3   3   4   5
4   4   5   6
```

I'm wondering how I can extend this apply() functions such that I simply unpack the entire dictionary such that the keys are the new column names. Obviously this is easy if I simply iterrows() over the df and then subloop over the keys, but you would all yell at me :)

I could even accept a solution that somehow stores the entire contents of the dictionary into a single cell, and then unpacks it as a second step.

Any thoughts/ideas?

Comment: " I simply unpack the entire dictionary such that the keys are the new column names."  -> can you elaborate on this? What are you trying to do exactly (with an example if possible)?

Comment: `df.apply(lambda x: func(x['A']), axis=1, result_type='expand')` is already expanding the keys as column names… maybe you want `df.join(df.apply(lambda x: func(x['A']), axis=1, result_type='expand'))`?

Comment: Using `apply(..., axis=1)` has the same behavior than `iterrows()`. It's a bit slow

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use [`eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.eval.html#pandas.eval) or [`numexpr.evaluate`](https://numexpr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html)?

```
# Replace your values by expressions
def func(df):
   d = {'B': 'A+1', 'C': 'A+2'}
   for col, expr in d.items():
       df[col] = df.eval(expr)

# Or with numexpr
# pip install numexpr
import numexpr as ne

def func(df):
   d = {'B': 'A+1', 'C': 'A+2'}
   for col, expr in d.items():
       df[col] = ne.evaluate(expr, local_dict=df)
```

Usage:

```
func(df)  # All operations are inplace
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   A  B  C
0  0  1  2
1  1  2  3
2  2  3  4
3  3  4  5
4  4  5  6
```